# Where can I find a complete list of the industry standard keymap?

Tags: shortcut

Where can I find a complete list of the industry standard keymap? Ideally with a comparison of what the blender standard keymap for that function would be.

I have found https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/keymap/industry_compatible.html#viewport and https://developer.blender.org/T54963 but they don't seem to be complete. For example I can't figure out what the industry standard to open the 'Add' menu (Shift + A in blender keymap)

Comment: *Edit > User Preferences > Keymap*

Comment: I tried looking there, but it doesn't help, as I can't find the commands I want. Ideally I would like to be able to search (Shift + A) then look in the columns next to it to know what the command is called and what the industry standard shortcut is.

Comment: There is a search box at the top, you can even search by operator or keys. Where does it fail for you?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks, I didn't see the key binding search, so When I search Blender for 'Shift + A' it shows as 'Object mode -> Add' but if I search industry standard for 'Add' it is not there for Objet mode, is it possible that the key-map does not exist in industry standard?

Answer (score 2):

The only official keymap document [can be found here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/keymap/industry_compatible.html).

The shortcuts you specifically mention, do not exist in the default keymap, though they can be added through python or by editing the keymap. There are some other addons or config files that might be more beneficial for you.

The closest thing to a full list can be [found here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I4qKqKsJJgOAZEPIFWc8r8XnCyc3seMPfoui_ThmXC8/edit#gid=0), but this has been edited a bit, so it's not 1 to 1.

There is also [Maya Config](https://gumroad.com/l/FKhQL), which turns Blender into a very similar Maya configuration.

I'm working on listing out all of the shortcuts and adding the ones I miss from the regular Blender shortcuts myself, I am going to try and keep it close to the industry compatible keymap as possible, I will post here again if I get an update for you.